# Linear Mixed-Effect Model: how to assign two subjects (random effects) of one observation to the same random effects term?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I have a performance measure (dependent variable "DV"), which I want to model using a hierarchical linear model (lmer()).

The DV is a performance measure for which two subjects have contributed.

In a simpler use-case, I would model a subject as random intercept (1|subject). However, as each DV is based on two subjects, I need to allocate each observation to 2 entries in the subjects term.

A quick (and wrong) workaround would be, to model two separate random effects (1|subject.A) & (1|subject.B). However, then I would for each subject have 2 distributions. Actually I'm not particularly interested in the effects of the single subjects, but rather in other (fixed effects) model terms. However, I want to include the subjects properly.

Does anyone have an idea about how to set up the random effects term properly?